# (8-1) - (4-2) - (2-4) - (1-8) responsive element grid - how to solve this with pure CSS?

Tags: html, css

On a responsive website I have the following HTML:

```
            <div id="fpma">
                <span class="fpm"></span>
                <span class="fpm"></span>
                <span class="fpm"></span>
                <span class="fpm"></span>
                <span class="fpm"></span>
                <span class="fpm"></span>
                <span class="fpm"></span>
                <span class="fpm"></span>
            </div>
```

The container #fpma has a variable width depending on the screen size. The elements inside .fpm have a fixed width. The  current CSS is as follows:

```
#fpma {
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%;
}

.fpm {
    width: 48px;
    height: 33px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 4px;
    background:url('images/bar.png') center center no-repeat;
}
```

With decreasing width of the parent container I want to break the items as follows:

1 row - 8 elements

2 rows - 4 elements

4 rows - 2 elements

8 rows - 1 element

Looking for a re-usable solution which does not require to change the HTML by adding additional wrappers.

Usage of any CSS 3 functionalities like nth-child, :before/:after,  flexbox and so on is welcome.

Looking for a solution which ***does not depend on media queries*** (as they require a fixed max-width / min-width). **If you can give a reason why it is not possible without media queries** and give a media query solution this will also be ok. I tried various approaches but no result yet.

It is o.k. to change the elements display form if required.

Comment: "as they require a fixed max-width / min-width" I'm not sure I understand why this is a particular problem? is it because you want the media queries to be dependent on the width of the element, which may change?

Comment: The most re-usable solution would work without always having to put in all the pixel values into the media queries therefore yes - thats basically the reason.

Comment: "With decreasing width of the parent container" ... so media queries?  restyling based on viewport width doesn't work like magic.  You might be able to get away with it with flexbox, but not with the current parameters.  You'd have to rely on wrapping, which doesn't care how many elements you have or if you prefer even numbers.

Comment: Do not think it is magic. Maybe there is a nice approach without media queries thats why I ask the question. There is no trivial answer however I think CSS 3 is probably providing a really nice way to do it. This problem occures very often so a good solution would be helpful.

Comment: ya good luck doing this without media queries ;)

Comment: @Blackbam, I'd recommend using a preprocessor, because then you can change a single variable and have various different CSS values updated accordingly.

Comment: True thats a workaround but can it be that hard to find a solution like "if not enough space, make a new row with equal amount of elements"?

Comment: @Blackbam, "can it be that hard" yes, CSS as a language wasn't designed to do such things and all layout based enhancements such as flexbox have been attempting to solve the problem while simultaneously not breaking every webpage that already exists, some of which are already broken. That said, here's a quick example using a preprocessor: http://codepen.io/zzzzBov/pen/eZrmwY

Comment: Not a bad solution thx. However somebody may post a "wow thats an awesome way to do it".

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this without @media, but you have fixed size of elements inside .fpm, that's allow you to count @media query when it should break for 2row, 4r, 8r, there is example for 2 row I just did, with same logic you can do it for 4,8.

```css
#fpma {
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border:1px solid red;
}

.fpm {
    width: 48px;
    height: 33px;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin: 4px;
    background:url('images/bar.png') center center no-repeat;
}
@media screen and (max-width:408px){
  #fpma:before, #fpma:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
  #fpma:after {
    clear: both;
  } 
  #fpma {
    *zoom: 1;
   }
  .fpm {
    float: right;
    }
  

  .fpm:nth-of-type(5n)
  {
    display: inline;
    clear: right;
    float: right;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="fpma">
                <span class="fpm">1</span>
                <span class="fpm">2</span>
                <span class="fpm">3</span>
                <span class="fpm">4</span>
                <span class="fpm">5</span>
                <span class="fpm">6</span>
                <span class="fpm">7</span>
                <span class="fpm">8</span>
            </div>
```

```
https://jsfiddle.net/vm0opbab/
```

I hope I got it right.

Comment: Thx. In firefox it did not work however I think thats at least a WITH media queries valid approach. I will accept if there is no solution without.

Comment: It work in my Firefox, what's not supported by Firefox in this code?

Comment: nvm approach is good. I just wonder if there is REALLY no solution without media queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this without media query or script, here is a simple sample using media query.

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/Bb2d7/855/)

Stack snippet

```css
#fpma {
  width: 100%;
}
.fpm {
  width: 48px;
  height: 33px;
  float: right;
  margin: 4px;
  background:url('http://placehold.it/100') center center no-repeat;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
  .fpm:nth-of-type(5) {
    clear: right;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 225px) {
  .fpm:nth-of-type(3),
  .fpm:nth-of-type(7) {
    clear: right;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 112px) {
  .fpm {
    clear: right;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="fpma">
  <span class="fpm"></span>
  <span class="fpm"></span>
  <span class="fpm"></span>
  <span class="fpm"></span>
  <span class="fpm"></span>
  <span class="fpm"></span>
  <span class="fpm"></span>
  <span class="fpm"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for 3 of the 4 cases.

If I set the container as a flexbox, and adjust margins, I get this

```css
#container {
  width: 581px;
  height: 450px;
  border: solid 1px red;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  animation: widen 6s infinite;
}

.box {
  width: 48px;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid 1px blue;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.sep1 {
  margin-right: 150px;
}

.sep1 + div {
  margin-left: -150px;
}

.sep2 {
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.sep2 + div {
  margin-left: -50px;
}

@keyframes widen {
  from {width: 110px;}
  to {width: 450px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="box">A</div>
    <div class="box">B</div>
    <div class="box sep2">C</div>
    <div class="box">D</div>
    <div class="box sep1">A</div>
    <div class="box">B</div>
    <div class="box sep2">C</div>
    <div class="box">D</div>
</div>
```

But the requirement for rows of 1 element breaks ...

May be someone can solve this last issue ?